# Simple progress report similar to OVH's status page

Tags: web-apps

Does anyone know about a site that offer a service similar to http://status.ovh.es/?

What I'm looking for is a simple page where I can list upcoming features/whatever and their respective progress bar, exactly like the link above. Nothing too fancy. Simple and functional.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, lol. The answer was at their page's footer. They are using: https://www.flyspray.org/